# GROUP BY and Clausule are making the query slow

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I have a basic query, however for some reason the Group By and "ee.endereco_estado_id=1" are slowing it down, if I take either one it runs fast

The cardinality is
cliente - endereco NxN(Many to many 'clientenendereco')
endereco - endereco_rua 1x1
endereco_rua - endereco_cidade 1xN
endereco_cidade - endereco_estado Nx1

DER: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkYwG.png

With Group By and "ee.estado_id = 1" (Slow):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLnK4.png

With just "ee.estado_id=1" (FAST):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt8pa.png

With just "GROUP By cli.cliente_id" (FAST):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6bzk.png

I would like to know if there is an alternative to so many Left Joins, and create a clean and efficient query, I really don't know why it's taking so long, I need both Group By and "ee.estado_id=1", but I can't, and, i would like to understand based on the answers because i want to improve and understand better mysql

Table:
clientenendereco ~ 4milions row
endereco ~ 4 milions row
cliente ~ 4 milions row
endereco_rua ~ 500k row
endereco_cidade ~ 21k row
endereco_estado ~ 26 row

The Query:

```
SELECT
      cli.cliente_id, cli.cliente_nome, ende.endereco_id, er.endereco_rua_nome, 
      ende.endereco_cep, ende.endereco_numero, eb.endereco_bairro_nome, 
      ec.endereco_cidade_nome, 
      ee.endereco_estado_id, ee.endereco_estado_uf
FROM cliente AS cli
INNER JOIN clientenendereco AS ce
ON cli.cliente_id = ce.cliente_id 
LEFT JOIN endereco AS ende
ON ende.endereco_id = ce.endereco_id
LEFT JOIN endereco_rua AS er 
ON er.endereco_rua_id = ende.endereco_rua_id 
LEFT JOIN endereco_cidade AS ec 
ON ec.endereco_cidade_id = er.cidade_id /*#estado#*/
LEFT JOIN endereco_estado AS ee 
ON ee.endereco_estado_id = ec.estado_id 
LEFT JOIN ruanbairro AS rnb
ON rnb.ruanbairro_id = ende.ruanbairro_id
LEFT JOIN endereco_bairro AS eb
ON eb.endereco_bairro_id = rnb.endereco_bairro_id
WHERE ee.endereco_estado_id = 1
GROUP BY cli.cliente_id
```

thanks!

Comment: 1) Incomplete GROUP BY produces non-deterministic output which makes no sense. 2) `WHERE ee.endereco_estado_id = 1`  makes all LEFT joins before INNER ones.

Comment: Why is my Group By incomplete? And if "ee.endereco_estado_id = 1" makes the Left Join triggered before inner join what way could I improve?

Comment: The Group By cli.cliente_id makes sense to me because due to Left Joins the clients are repeated and I need to unify them, on the other hand, I also need to select only those that satisfy "ee.endereco_estado_id = 1"

Comment: *Why is my Group By incomplete?* Each output column which is not an argument of aggregated function must be included into GROUP BY expression. Read about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL Mode.

Comment: *because due to Left Joins the clients are repeated and I need to unify them* The logic is lost. Imagine that there is a group of rows with the same `cli.cliente_id`. These rows have different values in another columns. GROUP BY collapses all rows into one. So a bunch of different values should be collapsed into one value in this output row... but what value of all possible? None defines this, and server will return one indefinitely (randomly) selected from all values... Do you think that this value can make sense?

Comment: If some of those are many-to-many tables, then follow the indexing rules here:  [_Many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)